# QTestLib: Undocumented command line argument -chart

Tags: qt, qt4, qtestlib

In Qt 4.6 QTestLib supports the command-line argument "-chart" (but this is undocumented).

A report.html is created, however neither Firefox 3.6 nor IE8 are able to display anything but the headline "Test". When I look into the html-file it has some JavaScript stuff and test results, so there should be something to display.

As -chart is undocumented, I'm not sure I use it the correct way.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using it in combination with the `-xml` option. I suspect the Javascript reads in an XML file to generate the chart, not sure though.

Also, it might have something to do with this Qt labs blog post: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/12/05/qtestlib-now-with-nice-graphs-pointing-upwards

Comment: Same result with -xml -chart.
It seems this is really still an experimental feature.

Comment: Maybe the JS code provides some hints? Could you please post it here?

Comment: Unfortunately the code is too big to post it here (over 88k characters). Seems to be a lot RegExp.
Any possibility to attach files here (it's only 80kB)?

Answer (score 0):

How about looking into the produced HTML file with a text editor?

Other than that, reading the source code of QTest might help.

I assume it's some semi complete experimental feature.

Comment: As I wrote in my initial post i see some JavaScript stuff inside the produced HTML file.